# Coverage: pragma: no branch with multiline statement

Tags: python-3.x, code-coverage, coverage.py

For the python `coverage` package, a missing `else` can be ignored for the resulting coverage by using `# pragma: no branch`.

It seems, that this is not working when breaking a long if statement in multiple lines like this:

```
if this_is_a_verylong_boolean_expression == True and another_long_expression \
    and here_another_expression:  # pragma: no branch
    do_something()
```

Is this a bug of `coverage` or intended behavior?
Is there a way to handle these kind of multiline statements and ignore the missing branch in the coverage? Or do I just have to accept the missing branches in my coverage summary?

Comment: I've written this up as https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/754

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is not exactly what you asked, but I would recommend that you refactor that line to not be so long.  I would guess that the code will be much more readable and maintainable if you change it to:

```
some_condition = this_is_a_verylong_boolean_expression
another_test = another_long_expression
last_check = here_another_expression
if some_condition and another_test and last_check:     # pragma: no branch
    do_something()
```

This gives you a chance to give these expressions mnemonic names.

On the coverage.py question itself: you can make the pragma work like this:

```
if (this_is_a_verylong_boolean_expression == True and another_long_expression   # pragma: no branch
    and here_another_expression):
    do_something()
```